# Doctrine many to many to many relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a "Listing" entity having one or more "Categories".
Each "Category" has zero or more "Fields". Each "Field" has one or more "Categories".
I would like to add a "Value" for each "Field" of each "Category" of the "Listing".

Here is the existing relations:

```
Listing <--1:N--> ListingCategory <--N:1--> Category
Category <--1:N--> CategoryField <--N:1--> Field
```

Here is the problematic relation :

```
Listing <----> Category <----> Field <--X--> Value
```

Here is the doctrine entities:
...

```
class Listing
{

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="listings")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="listing_category",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="listing_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $categories;
```

...

```
class Category
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Listing", mappedBy="categories")
     **/
    private $listings;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Field", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $fields;
```

...

```
class Field
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="fields")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_field",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="field_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $categories;
```

...

```
class Value
{

     //What should be the relations?
```

Use case example :

- Category1 has a Field1
- Listing1 has a Category1 and a Value1 for Field1
- Listing2 has a Category1 and Value2 for Field1

Comment: Can i know why this question is down voted without any comments and anonymously. Absolutely not constructive neither .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: Split many to many relations to "one to many and many to one" relations with composite keys.

```
Listing <--1:N--> ListingCategory <--N:1--> Category
Category <--1:N--> CategoryField <--N:1--> Field 
CategoryField <--1:N--> Value <--N:1--> ListingCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one Value for each Field, and one Field for each Value, the relationship will be OneToOne.

If each Field can have multiple values, the Relationship will be OneToMany from Field to Value and ManyToOne from Value to Field.

Aside from that, this design looks suspicious, as a Value might just be a variable in the Field Entity.

Comment: The Value can't be just a variable in the Field entity because each Listing can have a different Value for the same Field.
ex: 
- Category1 has a  Field1
- Listing1 has a Category1 and a Value1 for Field1
- Listing2 has a Category1 and Value2 for Field1

Comment: Your remark about one to many relationships is obvious.
I don't understand why you vote down my question. If you analyse it precisely i think you will find it useful because it is a not simple but  widespread schema.